# How to add tabbar controller as child view to parent view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITabBarController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabbar"];
    [self addChildViewController:controller];
    controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 500, 500);
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
    [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

How can I add tabbar viewcontroller as child view to uiviewcontroller in objective-C?

Comment: Aren't you doing it already `[self.view addSubview:controller.view];` ? otherwise be more specific on your problem

Comment: thanks, i did, but i can't see tabbar on my parent screen, that was my problem

Comment: Checked the frame ? 500 width is bigger than iphone screen width.

Comment: yes , its just for testing , i will correct it once my main problem will solve

Comment: @sss did u solve the problem? I have exactly the same problem. The tab bar controller should be added (because the first view controllers would call api and I saw it did call) but nothing is seen....

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned your already doing it here `[self.view addSubview:controller.view]`

The autoresizing mask of the view of the tabbar controller assumes the full size of its superview.

If you set the frame when instantiating the tabbar controller, be sure to change the `autoresizingMask` property of the tabbar's view so that it doesn't have flexible width or flexible right margin.

Answer (score 0):

You have created the frame for `UITabBarController *controller` as-

```
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(500,500, 500, 500);
```

the `x and y origin is 500`, it looks like that the tab bar controller is added but it's origin is outside the visible frame of the screen.

Comment: I have correct it but my main problem is still there

Comment: @sss have you tried to adapt the autoresizing mask ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabController") as? TabController {
        addChildViewController(controller)
        controller.view.frame = contentView.bounds
        contentView.addSubview(controller.view)
        controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
```

Here 'contentView' is the UIView positioned in ViewController